# trigger for a table cause indefinate execution in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, triggers, sql-server-2012

I wrote trigger for a table to get the data of same table and export .txt file, but it is keep on executing never complete execution. I did code like this

```
 create trigger monitorTrigger on test 
 for insert 
 as
 declare @sql varchar(8000)
 declare @cmdval varchar(8000)
 set @cmdval='"select * from test2.dbo.test"'
 SELECT @sql = 'bcp '+@cmdval+' queryout I:\File\mytest.txt -c -t -T -S YAMUNA\SQLEXPRESS'
```

appropriate answer would be appreciate.

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this with a trigger?

Comment: I'm fairly sure that whether it works or not, it is a really bad idea.

Comment: Is there any other way to achieve my requirement

Comment: yes I want to do because I have a table called testTable, user is allowed to insert data into the testTable. I want to export only updated data whenever there is update in testTable. So I have written another trigger that uses inserted table to get only updated data of testTable in another tempTable, here I'll write this trigger for tempTable to export data in .txt format. Finally I'll get updated data in .txt file.

Answer (score 0):

It's never a good idea to reference a table in a trigger for that same table. If you really need to do this try using the `inserted` special table which you can reference within the trigger. Perhaps insert the data from `inserted` into another table or a global temp table and then bcp that data out.

Still seems like a bad idea overall though.